# Java Two ArrayLists from One ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I have a List where I am storing 2 ArrayLists inside this.

```
metadataList.addAll(countryList);
metadataList.addAll(languageList);
```

In the other method, I want to access these two lists. I am trying this code:

```
List<String> countriesList = metadataValues.get(0);
List<String> languageList = metadataValues.get(1);
```

Its not allowing me to do above line showing error like: Cannot convert from String to List. Please tell me how can I access these two lists and do further process:

```
List<String> metadataValues = parseXml(metadata.xml);


System.out.println("metadataValues in first method ---->" + metadataValues.size());
List<String> countriesList = metadataValues.get(0);
List<String> languageList = metadataValues.get(1);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

if (countriesList.size() == 1 || languageList.size() == 1) {
    for (String cnt: countriesList) {
        video.setCountry(cnt);
    }
    for (String language: languageList) {
        video.setLanguage(language);
    }
}
if (countriesList.size() >= 2 || languageList.size() >= 2) {
    for (String s: countriesList) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(",");
    }
    for (String s1: languageList) {
        sb1.append(s1);
        sb1.append(",");
    }
}
if (sb.length() != 0) {
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("StringBuilder Value ------>" + sb.toString());
    video.setCountry(sb.toString());
}
if (sb1.length() != 0) {
    sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("StringBuilder Value ------>" + sb1.toString());
    video.setLanguage(sb1.toString());
}
```

Here is parseXml method:

```
private static List < String > parseXml(String xmlData)
throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource src = new InputSource();
    src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
    Document doc = builder.parse(src);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");
    Element line = null;
    Element line1 = null;
    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> languageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> metadataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        NodeList countryNodes = element.getElementsByTagName("Country");
        NodeList languageNodes = element.getElementsByTagName("Language");
        for (int j = 0; j < countryNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < languageNodes.getLength(); k++) {
                if (countryNodes != null) {
                    line = (Element) countryNodes.item(j);
                    if (line != null) {
                        countryList.add(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                    }
                }
                if (languageNodes != null) {
                    line1 = (Element) languageNodes.item(k);
                    if (line1 != null) {
                        languageList
                            .add(getCharacterDataFromElement(line1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        metadataList.addAll(countryList);
        metadataList.addAll(languageList);
        // System.out
        // .println("countryList.size() ----->" + countryList.size());
    }
    return metadataList;

}
```

Comment: perhaps you just want an array of (two) lists... or better, a Map<String, String> to store country and language spoken in this country (I presume)

Answer (score 2):

```
list != list of list
```

Change your declaration of list in `parseXml()` method.

```
List<String> metadataList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
List<List<String>> metadataList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

And add element to it as

```
metadataList.add(countryList);
metadataList.add(languageList);
```

Then you are able to retrieve those lists as single elements later.

Comment: @Suresh Atta - Thank you so much Suresh. This is working. I changed my code with the above declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two `List<String>` and add all entries (a single entry is a String) to the metadatalist. If you use the list's `get()` method, you will retreive the String at the specific index.

Either store the two lists in an array to reaccess both or use a `List<List<String>> metadatalist`. So you use the `add()` method to add both lists to your metadatalist and can access each list again.

Comment: @ kevcodez - Thanks for the explanation. Its true that its giving me as a single entry when I tried the above code.